# Unable to plot pandas dataframe data with plotly in pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm, plotly

I am trying to plot a pandas dataframe data using plotly in pycharm but it is not working. The following is the code snippet.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cufflinks as cf

cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns='A B C D'.split())
print(df.head())

df.iplot()
```

When I run the above code in pycharm, it is throwing the error

```
plotly.exceptions.PlotlyError: Because you didn't supply a 'file_id' in the call, we're assuming you're trying to snag a figure from a url. You supplied the url, '', we expected it to start with 'https://plot.ly'.
Run help on this function for more information.
```

Not sure what exactly going wrong here.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I presume you have a plotly account created?

Comment: I am trying to plot it offline. For offline, I don't think we need to create an account.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, *exactly* as it is, runs just fine in a Jupyter Notebook and produces this plot:

[image]

So the question boils down to how *you* are running your code in PyCharm. A Python console? IPython perhaps? In order for plotly and `iplot()` to function offline, I think you'll have to run this particular snippet in a Jupyter Notebook. But you can do that within PyCharm as well unider `File > New > Jupyter Notebook:`

[image]

You may have to make some additional installations, but that shouldn't be too hard at all.